# MKRouteStep step.instruction not localized

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm working on an app with mapKit, where I can find the current location and my destination with the MKRouteStep property. Now I want to translate these instructions in French.
How can I do it ?
 I tried NSLocalizedString, but it doesn't work.
In the Apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRouteStep_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKRouteStep/instructions), it says that the "The string in this property is localized according to the user’s language preferences.", my device is on French, but I've still got English instructions...

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
Just open the info.plist of your project,
 then add "Localizations" as Infomation Property List,
 it will create an array with "English", simply add another item with the language wanted (in my case "French")
Regards,